# VSTS build agent web proxy configuration

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2018

I am trying to configure a build agent to work with a proxy as per the documentation.

[Using VSTS Agent behind Proxy](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/start/proxyconfig.md)

.proxy set and being picked up, envriomental variables set but for some reason only the username is coming throuhg the password is left as undefined no matter how i set it. config.cmd, .env file , user variables.

```
Agent.ProxyUrl=http://proxy:8888
Agent.ProxyUsername=Domain\Username
Agent.ProxyPassword=undefined
```

Comment: From the ticket tag, it seems that you are using TFS 2018, right?  You could check if the agent version is v2.122.0. This version of the agent has known issues. Here is [a doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) about it.  You could try to download the newer version of the agent and check if it could work. https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/tags?after=v2.136.0

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT the build agent is 2.136.1

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT you are correct TFS2018 , as above version 2.136.1 of the agent, I might try downloading the atleast agent. Do you know if its supported by TFS2018?

Comment: According to the document above, TFS 2018 supports this feature.

Answer (score 0):

not sure of your setup above, but according to the [overview](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/start/proxyconfig.md) you pointed out you need to

1. Create a .proxy file in the agent's root containing only the proxy URL
2. Then you need 2 **environment** variables  VSTS_HTTP_PROXY_USERNAME and VSTS_HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD

I've had success with this setup, in fact I also used a proxy environment variable before, but can't find the exact name now.

Comment: I have set all that, it's very strange, I have even removed the agent and reconfigured it using ./config.cmd --proxyurl http://127.0.0.1:8888 --proxyusername "myuser" --proxypassword "mypass"